# Make Menus in Wordpress use menu-item name instead of number for list item ID?

Tags: php, wordpress

So after calling [wp_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) like:

`<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Primary Menu' )); ?>`

I end up with:

```
<li id="menu-item-1">
<li id="menu-item-2">
```

... `id`s like `menu-item-1`, `menu-item-2`, etc.

Is there some way to **replace the numbers with the title of the page** instead,so

`menu-item-1` becomes `menu-item-contact`,

`menu-item-2` becomes `menu-item-store`, etc?

Comment: I'm guessing I should start looking around in /wordpress/wp-admin/nav-menus.php?

Comment: The function is located in wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php, but I wouldn't edit core files just for that. May I ask what do you need the ids for? CSS hooks?

Comment: Yep, just CSS hooks. I wasn't going to edit the core files, just try to understand them.  Obviously the numeric versions work just fine, but are less intuitive and require copious notes/tables to keep track of what # is what item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to filter the ID using WordPress's `nav_menu_item_id` filter, which is applied in the [nav-menu-template.php file](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.1/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L79). It takes three arguments, but the second one is what we need to actually get the title of the menu item, and turn it into something useful for the ID attribute. Here's a function to do that, which works for me in WordPress 3.4.1:

```
function custom_nav_menu_item_id($id, $item) {
    $title = sanitize_title_with_dashes($item->title);
    return 'menu-item-'.$title;
}

add_filter('nav_menu_item_id', 'custom_nav_menu_item_id', 10, 2);
```

This uses another WordPress function to sanitize the title into a string usable for the ID attribute (or any other HTML attribute).

Note that this function get's the menu item's title, which migth be different than the post or page title if you change it in the Menu panel from the admin.

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy. Still working I just add [sanitize_title()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title) to remove accents and special char. 
`function custom_nav_menu_item_id($id, $item) {
    $title = sanitize_title_with_dashes(sanitize_title($item->title));
    return 'menu-item-'.$title;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Jeremy answer : I just add [sanitize_title()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title) to remove accents and special char.

```
    function custom_nav_menu_item_id($id, $item) {
        $title = sanitize_title_with_dashes(sanitize_title($item->title));
        return 'menu-item-'.$title;
    }
    add_filter('nav_menu_item_id', 'custom_nav_menu_item_id', 10, 2);
```

/** **for a better wp cleaning** [take a look @ this gist and include it in your function.php](https://gist.github.com/mi-ca/da982d172254dd7ddb8084ddac9c2661) */